# Reset Pseudo-Class Styling

Tags: css, pseudo-class

Is there any way to reset the styling in a pseudo-class to the default without the pseudo-class? This would be sort of like `initial`/`inherit` but for pseudo-classes rather than elements.

For example, Bootstrap sets `background: none` for all active buttons. I believe this prevents the default weird boxy clicked state that looks like it's from the 80's/90's (which it is). I would like to set the background as an image for some buttons, but it can get inconvenient/redundant to set it to the same value for each pseudo-class, even with a preprocessor like LESS/Sass.

Bootstrap's style:

```
.btn.active, .btn:active {
    background-image: none;
}
```

My proposed style:

```
.btn.active, .btn:active {
    background-image: non-pseudo-class-state;
}
```

Is there any way to do this in one place without setting it every single time?